# get java.lang.reflect.Method safely

Tags: java, methods, reflection, java-7

Similar `interface`s are used for an event system as "listeners"

```java
interface Updatable {
  void update();
}
```

Events (→ all "listen" methods) are called by

```java
spot(Method, Object... event);
```

*To achieve.* **Get `java.lang.reflect.Method` of "listeners" like `update` in `Updatable`.**

*Attempt.* An option is to use **reflection** (unsafe) to find out the `Method` to call

*Usage.* Create a **constant for every method** in the "listener" *interface* and use it as an argument

```java
interface Updatable {
  void update();
  Method UPDATE = method(Updatable.class, "update");
}
//anywhere
spot(UPDATE);
```

using this util function

```java
static public @Nullable Method method(Class<?> of, String name, Class... params) {
  try {
    return of.getDeclaredMethod(name, params);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {/*...*/}
}
```

*Questions.* Is there a

1. safer
2. simpler

way to get `reflect.Method`s in (< 8) java ?

Comment: Why did you not make use of anonymous inner classes instead of lambda expressions? You are correct with your assumption, that reflection is slow for such use.

Comment: Just use something like that: https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda

Comment: @Holger you are right, I removed the misleading java 8 code!

Comment: Actually, I do not understand the problem you are trying to solve. What are you trying to achieve? You talk a lot about **how** you want to do something but not **what** you are trying to achieve. This seems to be an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). I don't get your brief explanation about interfaces and callbacks. I think an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of an incoherent set of isolated code snippets would help tremendously.

Comment: @kriegaex ok, I editted my question. My basic question is: Is there a simple way to get a class's method, since try catch can not be used in static blocks of interfaces?

Comment: Just use normal anonymous classes (or lambdas using this retrolambda linked above) and register a function to call each of this methods somewhere, then you don't need any reflections

Comment: @GotoFinal Good idea! Now I understand.  Let me give the bounty to you if you write this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use normal functional classes to do this in java 7, it's not pretty but works fine, and if you want to make it prettier you can use something like https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda that will allow you to use lambdas in java 7 that will be compiled to anonymous inner classes.

```
Listener listenerMethod = new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
        updatable.update();
    }
});
// anywhere, or in that "spot" method:
listenerMethod.onEvent();
```

And with retrolambda just

```
Listener listenerMethod = () -> updatable.update();
```

or something similar depending how your system looks like.

Comment: in my case: spot(new Signal<Updatable>(){@Override public void spot(Updatable u){ u.update(); }});